# Creating a class in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to create a class in angularjs with a constructor, getter, setter, variables and methods?

Here is example of what I want to make in angulajs

```
class Abc {
int a;
string str ="Hello world";

  public Abc(){
  }

  public show(){
   return str;
  }

  public setStr(string str){
  this.str = str;
  }

  public getStr(){
  return this.str;
  }
}
```

I don't want to use any type script.

Just want to know how to make a class in angularjs with the following abilities.

Comment: create service, factory to achieve your requirement

Comment: @StarkButtowski , can you give me an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: Classes in JavaScript was introduced in ES6, you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes. ES6 is only compatible with modern browsers, but that won't be a problem if you use a compiler like Babel.

Comment: @HassanRaza You actually want to use TypeScript, you just don't know it yet :P

Comment: Why my post is down voted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the way JS or angular work.

> Update

Since what you are trying to do is to be able to create new instances, you should probably create this in a service, and then in the controller you can inject your service.

For example:

```
angular.module('app', function(){

});

angular.module('app').factory('Abc', function(){
    return {
        a: 0,
        str: "Hello world",
        show:  function() {
            return str;
        },
        setStr: function(str) {
            this.str = str;
        },
        getStr: function() {
            return str;
        }
    }
});

angular.module('app').controller('myController', function(Abc) {
     $scope.newClass = new Abc;
});
```

> Old answer.

Instead you create objects which have there own properties, usually inside the $scope of your controller.

An equivalent angular code to your code would be:

```
angular.module('app', function(){

});

angular.module('app').controller('Abc', function(){
    $scope.a;

    var str = "Hello world";

    $scope.show = function() {
        return str;
    };

    $scope.setStr = function(str) {
        str = str;
    };

    $scope.getStr = function() {
        return str;
    };
});
```

Comment: I am asking a way , if there is not, then how do we create a class in angularjs ?

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: sorry, took me a minute to elaborate and explain the answer.

Comment: @RabbiShuki what to do , if i want to instantiate an object of my class Abc ?

Comment: @HassanRaza you mean add a new property?

Comment: @RabbiShuki i meant how to initialize a new object of my class Abc 
like Abc abc = new Abc();

Answer (score 1):

> Before introduced ES6, there are no classes in JavaScript. Functions can be used to somewhat simulate classes, but in general JavaScript is a class-less language. Everything is an object. And when it comes to inheritance, objects inherit from objects, not classes from classes as in the "class"-ical languages.And  you can get more idea from this below article [**3 ways to define a JavaScript class**](https://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)

- You can't create a class like angular 2. But you can use factory/service as a class.

For example

```
angular.module('foo', [])
.factory('Foo', ['$http', function($http) {
  return function(a, b) {
    this.arr = [];
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.random = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);

    this.someFunc = function(c) {
      this.arr.push(c);
    };
  };
}]);
```

Now you can call that factory like a class

```
var f1 = new Foo('A', 'B');
f1.random;  // i.e. 0
f1.someFunc('z');  // only affects f1.arr
var f2 = new Foo('C', 'D');
f2.random;  // i.e. 8
f2.someFunc('y');  // only affects f2.arr
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you out

[Angular model objects with JavaScript classes](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc)

> In this article, the author has used prototype to demonstrate the use of
>   class. If you want to use `class` keyword, you can use that as well.
>   Which is just syntactical sugar to the `prototypes` in javascript.

Just create a factory of the class you want to use and import in the modules you want to use the custom class.

```
app.factory('Rectangle', function () {

  class Rectangle {
   constructor(height, width) {
     this.height = height;
     this.width = width;
    }
     get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  } 
 }
  return Rectangle;
})
```

Just a class way of implementing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to create a class-like object in Javascript.

ECMA6 introduces the `class` keyword. However, this is for later browsers, and there were already practices in place for creating classes that works on earlier browsers:

```
function ABC {
    this.str = "Hello world";
}

ABC.prototype.show = function() {
    return this.str;
};

ABC.prototype.setStr = function(str) {
    this.str = str;
}

ABC.prototype.getStr = function() {
    return this.str;
}
```

You can now treat ABC like a class:

```
var abc = new ABC();
abc.setStr('Maybe I should look at typescript');
console.log(abc.getStr());
```

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you suggest TypeScript directly. It kinda feels like you only give a slight hint in a code-string :3

Comment: @AllTheFish - the question explicitly said no typescript, and I was honouring the wishes of the question. That was just a snippet of random text  ;-)

Comment: You are right. he added the part with "no TypeScript" later if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `factory`:

```
function Abc() {
    this.str = "This is a string";
    this.i = null;
    this.show() {
        return str;
    }

    this.setStr = function(str){
        this.str = str;
    }

    this.getStr = function(){
        return this.str;
    }
}

module.factory('Abc', function () {
  return Abc;
});
```

You can use it in your controller:

```
function MainCtrl(Abc) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.abc= new Abc();
}
```

See another example [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide#services).